# update_user_meta not updating

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a custom meta for a users phone number. I was excpeting the `update_user_meta` function to add a row with the users phone number. Here's the code:

```
add_action( "personal_options_update", "save_custom_user_field" );
add_action( "edit_user_profile_update", "save_custom_user_field" );

function save_custom_user_field(){

if( defined( "IS_PROFILE_PAGE" ) && IS_PROFILE_PAGE ){

        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

}

if( !isset( $_POST[ "user_phone" ] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ "user_phone" ], "update-user_" . $user_id ) ){

    return;

}

if( !current_user_can( "edit_user", $user_id ) ) {

    return;

}

update_user_meta( $user_id, "user_phone", $_POST[ "user_phone" ] );

}
```

Comment: how you get the value of `$user_id`? it is correct?

Comment: when you enter the user-edit page in WordPress it automatically puts the `user_id` in the parameters. Example: wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=17